# How to automate creating credentials in a secure way

Tags: sql-server-2016, powershell

We have created an automated process to stand up a new SQL Server using TFS and powershell.  As part of a new server build, we deploy a database and a set of jobs for dba use.  As part of the install we need to create a credential for a sql agent proxy for some of our jobs.  However, we don't want to store our passwords in code.

Is there a solution to storing passwords (or generating a password) where we aren't storing it in plain text or in line in the code?

Our servers are on-prim, not in Azure.  We have access to Keepass, but that is being deprecated for Thycotic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage PowerShell and the [Thycotic REST API](https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/REST-API-PowerShell-Scripts-Getting-Started) to fetch your credentials from Secret Server programmatically. Use "Windows Authentication" to avoid having to store credentials in the PowerShell scripts, or enter them during runtime.

If your deployments run under a build agent service account context, then you need to ensure that service account has access in Secret Server to the credentials you want to access.

Leveraging the API as a step in your release prior to deploying the SQL credential, you can fetch the credential and pass it to the PowerShell script that deploys the credential.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$cred = get-credential
$cred | Export-CliXml -Path C:\Temp\Mycreds.xml
```

Get-Credential will prompt for the username & password & the Export-CliXml will export the results to an XML file. If you look at the username it will be in plaintext but the password will be encrypted.

When the username & password is needed, import the XML:

```
$cred = Import-CliXml -Path "C:\Temp\Mycreds.xml"
```

Then in your connection string you can use the username & password like this.

```
-Username $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Username 
-Password $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Another hacky, **much less secure** way to do this would be to write a secure string to a file.

```
## Create the secure string password file
$Sec = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$Enc = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $Sec -Key (1..16)
$Enc | Set-Content C:\Temp\Encrypted.txt

## When you need to use it...
$Sec2 = Get-Content C:\Temp\Encrypted.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (1..16)
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR((($Sec2))))
```

if you leave the file extensions off (Encrypted.txt would be Encrypted), anyone browsing the folder the file is in wouldn't know it was a regular text file.

*But this is really security through obscurity, anyone that can read the script could use what you are doing and collect the password.*

Comment: So I read into export-clixml, and it says only I can use the XML on the same machine I created it on.  There are 6 people on my team who would use this.  Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: In your post you said you'd "create a credential for a sales agent proxy". Will not run under that account? Ideally you would setup a scheduled task with the "Run As" being that account. I'll add a hacky second option as well.